# Сравнение элементов и скрытие повторяющихся

Tags: php, jquery

Добрый день! 
Имеется каталог мест. Места выгружаются в виде листа, с разных источников, в связи с чем возникают повторения. Так как разные источники предоставляют данные в разном формате, то сравнить места можно только по названию - оно вполне одинаково.

В результате создал такую конструкцию:

```
<div class="container_a"> // внешний блок
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$placename?>" class="container_one"/> // скрытый инпут с именем для сравнения
<div class="inside_container"> // внутренние блоки
</div>
</div>

<div class="container_b"> // внешний блок для другого источника данных
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$placename?>" class="container_two"/> // скрытый инпут с именем для сравнения, из другого источника данных
<div class="inside_container"> // внутренние блоки
</div>
</div>
```

Решил присобачить к этому решение jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($('container_one').val() == $('container_two').val()){
$('container_two').parent().hide();
};
});
```

Но в целом ничего не сработало - ведь jquery проверил значения только первых двух инпутов с классами "container_one" и "container_two".

Задача же заключается в то что бы сверить все инпуты и если их value совпадают - спрятать родителя второго.

Не могу придумать как это сделать.

Сделать выборку до выгрузки данных на страницу - увы нельзя.

Comment: Попробуйте через [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr = [];

$('input[type="hidden"]').each(function (key, val){
    $this = $(this).val();
    if($.inArray( $this, arr) !== -1){
 $(this).parent().hide()
    }else{
 arr.push($this);
    }
   
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container_a"> // внешний блок
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$placename?>" class="container_one"/> // скрытый инпут с именем для сравнения
<div class="inside_container"> // внутренние блоки
</div>
</div>

<div class="container_b"> // внешний блок для другого источника данных
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$placename?>" class="container_two"/> // скрытый инпут с именем для сравнения, из другого источника данных
<div class="inside_container"> // внутренние блоки
</div>
</div>

<div class="container_c"> // внешний блок для другого источника данных
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$placename?>" class="container_three"/> // скрытый инпут с именем для сравнения, из третьего источника данных
<div class="inside_container"> // внутренние блоки
</div>
</div>

<div class="container_d"> // внешний блок для другого источника данных
<input type="hidden" value="<?=$placename2?>" class="container_four"/> // скрытый инпут с именем для сравнения, из четвертого источника данных, другой инпут
<div class="inside_container"> // внутренние блоки
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нет, увы, не срабатывает вообще. Можете чуть-чуть откоментировать JS? А то я в нем не силен.

Comment: @DantheHat что именно у вас не срабатывает? По коду, который я привел, если нажать выполнить, два блока скрывается, а четвертый, который уникальный нет.
Я по вашему примеру создал. Если у вас немного другая структура html, то скажите, я подредактирую.
А так, создаем пустой массив. Через `.each` мы берем каждый инпут, в котором есть  `type="hidden"`, смотрим есть ли его значение у нас в массиве. Если нет - то записываем его в массив и идем дальше, если же уже есть, то тогда `.parent().hide()` скрываем родителя инпута.

Comment: Все, сработало, где-то я протупил. Спасибо большое)))